# iOS Coredata unable to open sqlite database file

Tags: ios, iphone, sqlite, core-data

How to open sqlite database when we use coredata in iOS ?
In my case it shows three database files :

1. (appname).sqlite
2. (appname).sqlite-shm
3. (appname).sqlite-wal

When I tried to open via terminal it shows file is corrupted or encrypted. Can anyone guide me...

Comment: Only the first one is the database `(appname).sqlite` the others are shared memory file and write-ahead-log file for sqlite

Comment: How did you try to open it via terminal?

Answer (score 1):

get the three file into the desktop and open with 
mozillafirefox->tools->SQLiteManager

Comment: I did the same thing but SQLiteManager is not opening any file.

Comment: yes,that will allows you in the first time only, if you tried to open in a second time may be that you can't access,try it this one once, open your file path from SQLiteManager

Comment: It looks that the something is different in the Core Data sqlite format. Maybe it is encrypted now.

Comment: @Hola Soy Edu Feliz Navidad Yes, now its not getting opened.

Answer (score 0):

After closing my application and Xcode . I opened database file in sqlite manager of mozilla. File opened successfully.

The main thing is your app should be closed.